# How to save a huge pandas dataframe to hdfs?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyarrow, apache-arrow

Im working with pandas and with spark dataframes. The dataframes are always very big (> 20 GB) and the standard spark functions are not sufficient for those sizes. Currently im converting my pandas dataframe to a spark dataframe like this:

```
dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_dataframe)
```

I do that transformation because with spark writing dataframes to hdfs is very easy:

```
dataframe.write.parquet(output_uri, mode="overwrite", compression="snappy")
```

But the transformation is failing for dataframes which are bigger than 2 GB.
If I transform a spark dataframe to pandas I can use pyarrow:

```
// temporary write spark dataframe to hdfs
dataframe.write.parquet(path, mode="overwrite", compression="snappy")

// open hdfs connection using pyarrow (pa)
hdfs = pa.hdfs.connect("default", 0)
// read parquet (pyarrow.parquet (pq))
parquet = pq.ParquetDataset(path_hdfs, filesystem=hdfs)
table = parquet.read(nthreads=4)
// transform table to pandas
pandas = table.to_pandas(nthreads=4)

// delete temp files
hdfs.delete(path, recursive=True)
```

This is a fast converstion from spark to pandas and it also works for dataframes bigger than 2 GB. I yet could not find a way to do it the other way around. Meaning having a pandas dataframe which I transform to spark with the help of pyarrow. The problem is that I really cant find how to write a pandas dataframe to hdfs.

My pandas version: 0.19.0

Comment: What error you get?
Are you sure that the application fails in writing or maybe a bit before (during the dataframe transformations) ?

Comment: It fails with out of memory exception because the java heap space is limitted and the createDataFrame method is building a byte array on the java heap. To get around this we need the pyarrow solution. as described it already works perfectly for spark to pandas. but I also need pandas to spark since I cant find a way to save pandas directly to hdfs or hive.

Comment: Just curious -- at this size, why not just write the data to a database? Postgres, for example, if you still want to write Python or C code to operate on it in-database.

Comment: An hack could be to create N pandas dataframes (each less than 2 GB) (horizontal partitioning) from the big one and create N different  spark dataframes, then merging (Union) them to create a final one to write into HDFS. I am assuming that your master machine is powerful but you also have available a cluster in which you are running Spark.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Meaning having a pandas dataframe which I transform to spark with the help of pyarrow.

[`pyarrow.Table.fromPandas`](https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/42fc57be9c768add32b278adbee2f6f30b10005d/python/pyarrow/table.pxi#L679-L705) is the function your looking for:

> ```
> Table.from_pandas(type cls, df, bool timestamps_to_ms=False, Schema schema=None, bool preserve_index=True)
>
> Convert pandas.DataFrame to an Arrow Table
> ```

```
import pyarrow as pa

pdf = ...  # type: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
adf = pa.Table.from_pandas(pdf)  # type: pyarrow.lib.Table
```

The result can be written directly to Parquet / HDFS without passing data via Spark:

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

fs  = pa.hdfs.connect()

with fs.open(path, "wb") as fw
    pq.write_table(adf, fw)
```

**See also**

- [@WesMcKinney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/776560/wes-mckinney) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47443889/6910411) to [read a parquet files from HDFS using PyArrow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47443151/6910411/).
- [Reading and Writing the Apache Parquet Format](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html) in the [`pyarrow` documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/index.html).
- [Native Hadoop file system (HDFS) connectivity in Python](http://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-hdfs-interfaces/)

**Spark notes**:

Furthermore since Spark 2.3 (current master) Arrow is supported directly in `createDataFrame` ([SPARK-20791 - Use Apache Arrow to Improve Spark createDataFrame from Pandas.DataFrame](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20791)). It [uses `SparkContext.defaultParallelism` to compute number of chunks](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/64817c423c0d82a805abd69a3e166e5bfd79c739/python/pyspark/sql/session.py#L515) so you can easily control the size of individual batches.

Finally `defaultParallelism` can be used to control number of partitions generated using standard `_convert_from_pandas`, effectively reducing size of the slices to something more manageable.

Unfortunately these are unlikely to resolve your [current memory problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393001/how-to-save-a-huge-pandas-dataframe-to-hdfs/47541073#comment82022570_47393001). Both depend on `parallelize`, therefore store all data in memory of the driver node. Switching to Arrow or adjusting configuration can only speedup the process or address block size limitations.

In practice I don't see any reason to switch to Spark here, as long as you use local Pandas `DataFrame` as the input. The most severe bottleneck in this scenario is driver's network I/O and distributing data won't address that.

Answer (score 1):

From https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235

> Support for parallelizing R data.frame larger than 2GB

is resolved.

From https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/r_interface.html

> Converting DataFrames into R objects

you can convert a pandas dataframe to an R data.frame

So perhaps the transformation pandas -> R -> Spark -> hdfs?

Answer (score 1):

One other way is to convert your pandas dataframe to spark dataframe (using pyspark) and saving it to hdfs with save command.
example

```
    df = pd.read_csv("data/as/foo.csv")
    df[['Col1', 'Col2']] = df[['Col2', 'Col2']].astype(str)
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
    sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
    sdf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df)
```

Here `astype` changes type of your column from `object` to `string`. This saves you from otherwise raised exception as spark couldn't figure out pandas type `object`. But make sure these columns really are of type string.

Now to save your df in hdfs:

```
    sdf.write.csv('mycsv.csv')
```

Answer (score -1):

An hack could be to create N pandas dataframes (each less than 2 GB) (horizontal partitioning) from the big one and create N different spark dataframes, then merging (Union) them to create a final one to write into HDFS. I am assuming that your master machine is powerful but you also have available a cluster in which you are running Spark.