# read a parquet files from HDFS using PyArrow

Tags: hdfs, parquet, pyarrow

I know I can connect to an HDFS cluster via pyarrow using `pyarrow.hdfs.connect()`

I also know I can read a parquet file using `pyarrow.parquet`'s `read_table()`

However, `read_table()` accepts a filepath, whereas `hdfs.connect()` gives me a `HadoopFileSystem` instance.

Is it somehow possible to use just pyarrow (with libhdfs3 installed) to get a hold of a parquet file/folder residing in an HDFS cluster? What I wish to get to is the `to_pydict()` function, then I can pass the data along.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
fs = pa.hdfs.connect(...)
fs.read_parquet('/path/to/hdfs-file', **other_options)
```

or

```
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
with fs.open(path) as f:
    pq.read_table(f, **read_options)
```

I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-1848 about adding some more explicit documentation about this

Comment: Thanks! just to make sure- Do they both use the same mechanism? Does read_table() accept "file handles" in general?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same via Pydoop library and engine = pyarrow and it worked perfect for me.Here is the generalized  method.

```
!pip install pydoop pyarrow
import pydoop.hdfs as hd

#read files via Pydoop and return df

def readParquetFilesPydoop(path):
    with hd.open(path) as f:
        df = pd.read_parquet(f ,engine='pyarrow')
        logger.info ('file: ' +  path  +  ' : ' + str(df.shape))
        return df
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read and write with pyarrow as depicted in the accepted answer. However the APIs provided there are long deprecated and don't work with recent versions of hadoop. Use:

```
from pyarrow import fs
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

# connect to hadoop
hdfs = fs.HadoopFileSystem('hostname', 8020) 

# will read single file from hdfs
with hdfs.open_input_file(path) as pqt:
     df = pq.read_table(pqt).to_pandas()

# will read directory full of partitioned parquets (ie. from spark)
df = pq.ParquetDataset(path, hdfs).read().to_pandas()
```