# how to write a Pandas dataframe in HDFS

Tags: python, pandas, hadoop, hdfs

I want to write a Pandas dataframe in HDFS, just like that

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(4).reshape(2,2),columns=['a','b'])
data.to_csv('/localpath/test.csv')
"""
the outputfile will be :
   a  b
0  0  1
1  2  3

"""
```

to_csv() will write to a local path, but how can I write the panda dataframe to hdfs and the file in hdfs the same as the file output in localpath?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you search for this? https://creativedata.atlassian.net/wiki/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=61177860#content/view/61177860

Comment: that's what I want! Thanks

Comment: is the solution given working ? Because when I tried running the same code as in the link I get the following error: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'hdfs.util.AsyncWriter'>

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47393001/how-to-save-a-huge-pandas-dataframe-to-hdfs