# How to save pandas DataFrame to Hive within `forearchPartition` (PySpark)

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, rdd

I have a PySpark DataFrame. I want to perform some function `forearchPartition` and then save each result to Hive. The result is a pandas dataframe (within each partition). What is the best way to do this?

I have tried the following without success (gives a serialization error):

```
def processData(x):
    #do something
    spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)
    spark_df.write.mode("append").format("parquet").saveAsTable(db.table_name)

original_spark_df.rdd.forearchPartition(processData)
```

I guess, one solution would be to turn pandas into RDD and return it (using `mapPartitions` instead of `forearchPartition`), and then use `rdd.toDF()` and `saveAsTable()`.

Is there some solution to save the pandas to Hive within `forearchPartition`?

Comment: [How to save a huge pandas dataframe to hdfs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47393001/9613318)

Comment: If I just save pandas as parquet files, how will Hive update it's metadata?

Comment: `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` (Hive) / `REFRESH TABLE` (Spark). What you describe in the question is just not allowed (to be honest I am not sure why would you choose this design).

Comment: I want to run a Machine Learning task with each partition's data and save some output to Hive. I'm fine with transforming pandas DF to an intermediate format before saving to Hive.

Comment: So why not convert the result of `mapPartitions` back to Spark `DataFrame` for saving. Or just use `pandas_udf`?

Comment: I actually want to save two dataframes within each partition. That's why I don't want to return back to Spark DF.

Comment: In that case, the linked solution (or a similar one, like using one of Python Hive clients ) is the only choice you have.