# What should I add to the code to avoid 'exceeds max allowed bytes' error using pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataframe with 4 million rows and 10 columns.  I am trying to write this to a table in hdfs from the Cloudera Data Science Workbench using pyspark.  I am running into an error when trying to do this:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 1) / 
2]19/02/20 12:31:04 ERROR datasources.FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Serialized task 0:0 was 318690577 bytes, which exceeds max allowed: spark.rpc.message.maxSize (134217728 bytes). Consider increasing spark.rpc.message.maxSize or using broadcast variables for large values.
```

I can break up the dataframe into 3 dataframes and perform the spark write 3 seperate times but I would like to do this just one time if possible by possibly adding something to the spark code like `coalesce`.

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('BulkWhois/2019-02-20_Arin_Bulk/Networks_arin_db_2-20-2019_parsed.csv')

'''PYSPARK'''
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark import SparkContext
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Arin_Network').getOrCreate()

schema = StructType([StructField('NetHandle', StringType(), False),
                     StructField('OrgID', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Parent', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('NetName', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('NetRange', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('NetType', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Comment', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('RegDate', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Updated', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Source', StringType(), True)])

dataframe = spark.createDataFrame(df, schema)
dataframe.write. \
  mode("append"). \
  option("path", "/user/hive/warehouse/bulkwhois_analytics.db/arin_network"). \
  saveAsTable("bulkwhois_analytics.arin_network")
```

Comment: Why do you load data with Pandas, instead of using Spark directly? If that's because you don't want to copy data to a distributed storage, then using Spark makes little sense, and it might be better to [consider other options](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47393001/10465355)

Comment: I am going to take a look at this @user10465355

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User10465355 mentioned that I should use Spark directly.  Doing this is simpler and the correct way to accomplish this.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('Networks').getOrCreate()

dataset = spark.read.csv('Networks_arin_db_2-20-2019_parsed.csv', header=True, inferSchema=True)
dataset.show(5)

dataset.write \
  .mode("append") \
  .option("path", "/user/hive/warehouse/analytics.db/arin_network") \
  .saveAsTable("analytics.arin_network")
```